# Make loop and code more efficient to handle large numbers with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop, coding-efficiency

this is an assignment on Codewars, in other words like a homework. :) 
I have to write a function that returns the amount of numbers between 1 and `n` (inclusive) that can be represented as the difference of two perfect squares. For example,  `20 = 6² - 4²` and `21 = 5² - 2²`. Many numbers can be written this way, but not all.

I wrote a function, it works well, but it needs to be able to handle `n` values up to `45000`. Basically my code crashes when it gets to analyze numbers in the order of thousands. In order to make the code more efficient, I tried to reverse the initial loop, from `n` to `0` instead than from `0` to `n`. I have tried to divide the `n` by two until it gets small enough and then multiply the final result times 2 again, but didn't work. I also used a `while` loop, but then I realized that I simply don't know how to solve this issue, and after 3 days of pointless attempts to solve it with brute force, I am asking for help as I don't want to just give up on it . This is my code

```
function countSquareable(n){
  var y = []
  var c = []

  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) { // all numbers powered in range
  y.push(Math.pow(i,2))
  }

for(i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    c.push(y.map(a => y[i]-a)) //  all subtractions' combos

}

var d = c.toString().split(",").sort(function(a, b){return a-b}).filter(function(a) {return a>0 && a<=n}) // only the combos I need in the range

var a = [], b = [], prev; // remove duplicates
d.sort();
    for ( var i = 0; i < d.length; i++ ) {
        if ( d[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(d[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = d[i];
    }

return console.log(a.length) // end result



};
countSquareable(500)

countSquareable(4) // should return 3 and it works
countSquareable(5) // should return 4 and it works
countSquareable(40) // should return 30 and it works
countSquareable(45000) // should return 33750 but crashes
countSquareable(6427), // should return 4820 but crashes
```

How do I make a code SO MUCH more efficient to solve the issue?
The kata is [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/how-many-differences-of-squares/train/javascript).
thanks!!

Comment: first : do not use Math.Pow(x, 2), use x*x instead

Comment: don't know the maths behind that, but is n = a²-b² with a,b > n a valid solution?

Comment: maybe, but I need to return the exact amount of numbers that fulfill that condition

Comment: @RegisPortalez: The math won't support it.  `a^2 - b^2 = (a - b) * (a + b)`, so if either (positive) term is `> n`, then `(a + b) > n`, and the whole expression is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do with a small dose of math.

If instead of counting the values, you can list them, say the thirty of them for 40, you get

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21,
 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40]
```

If it's difficult to see the pattern there, try reading it aloud.  The point is that these group easily as

```
[        1,
 3,  4,  5,
 7,  8,  9,
 11, 12, 13,
 15, 16, 17,
 19, 20, 21,
 23, 24, 25,
 27, 28, 29,
 31, 32, 33,
 35, 36, 37,
 39, 40, (41)]
```

In other words, every fourth number is missing, starting with 2.  Here's code that follows that pattern:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => Array(...Array(hi - lo + 1)).map((_, n) => lo + n)

const countSquareable = (n) => range(1, n).filter(n => n % 4 !== 2).length

console.log(countSquareable(4))
console.log(countSquareable(5))
console.log(countSquareable(40))
console.log(countSquareable(45000))
```

So it matches the expectations.  But we're in the territory of math now, so we need to prove things.  We can do this in three cases:

### Can `n` be represented as the difference of squares?

#### Case 1: `n` is odd

Let `a = (n + 1) / 2`, let `b = (n - 1) / 2`.

Since `n` is odd, `n - 1` and `n + 1` are even, so `a` and `b` are both integers.

```
a^2 = (n^2 + 2n + 1) / 4
b^2 = (n^2 - 2n + 1) / 4
```

so

```
a^2 - b^2 = 4n / 4 = n
```

Hence, an odd number can be represented as the difference of squares.

#### Case 2: n is divisible by 4

Let `a = (n / 4 + 1)`, let b = `(n / 4 - 1)`

Since `n` is divisible by 4, `(n / 4) is an integer and thus`a`and`b` are integers.

Now

```
a^2 = (n^2/16 + 2n/4 + 1)
b^2 = (n^2/16 - 2n/4 + 1)
```

and

```
a^2 - b^2 = 4n/4 = n
```

Hence, a multiple of 4 can be represented as the difference of squares.

#### Case 3: A multiple of 2 that's not a multiple of 4

We can divide the integers up this way: `(4n), (4n + 1), (4n + 2), (4n + 3)`.

squaring each of these, and choosing an appropriate `k` we get:

```
(4n)^2 = 16n^2 = 4 * 4n^2                             = (4k)
(4n + 1)^2 = (16n^2 + 8n + 1) = 4(4n^2 + 2n) + 1,     = (4k + 1)
(4n + 2)^2 = (16n^2 + 16n + 4) = 4(4n^2 + 4n + 1)     = (4k)
(4n + 3)^2 = (16n^2 + 24n + 9) = 4(4n^2 + 6n + 2) + 1 = (4k + 1)
```

So the only remainders possible when dividing a square by 4 are 0 and 1.

Subtracting those, we get `(1 - 0) = 1`, `(1 - 1) = 0`, `(0 - 0) = 0`, `(0 - 1) = -1` (this last is the same as a remainder of 3: 4k - 1 = 4(k -1) + 3.)

So we can get remainders of `0`, `1`, or `3`.  But we cannot get `2`.

Hence, a multiple of 2 that's not a multiple of 4 cannot be represented as the difference of squares.

Q.E.D.  We've proven our intuition correct: Any integer can be written as the difference of squares except for those that are multiples of 2 but not of 4.

---

### Update

My original code was a brute-force approach, noting that `a^2 - b^2 = (a - b) * (a + b)` and that hence the smaller factor (`(a - b)`) had to be less than the square root of our top number if the product would be less than `n`.  Then I tried all the possible values of `b`, saving `(a^2 - b^2)` if it was less than `n`.  This works, and seems efficient enough for the `45000` case.  But it misses the analysis above.

In any case, here is that version:

```js
const countSquareable = (n) => {
  const found = new Set()
   // a^2 - b^2 = (a - b)(a + b), so (a - b) can be no larger than sqrt(n)
  const topDiff = Math.sqrt(n)
  for (let diff = 1; diff <= topDiff; diff++) {
    const topB = n / 2 // can we get a tighter bound here?
    for (let b = 0; b < topB; b++) {
      let a = b +  diff
      const val = (a * a) - (b * b)
      if (val <= n) {
        found.add(val)
      }
    }
  }
  //console.log([...found].sort((a, b) => a - b))
  return found.size
}

console.log(countSquareable(45000))
```

Comment: Man, thanks so much for writing that much and in that much detail. I was completely off task trying to solve this with brute force. Amazing work! I'm out of words to thank you enough, more for the explanation than for the solution itself.

Comment: Well, I started with a brute force approach -- one a little more efficient than your, perhaps because I noted that `a^2 - b^2 = (a - b) * (a + b)`.  Only after I had this working did I notice the pattern, and simplified to this.  Perhaps I'll post that version.  But also note that mine might better be rewritten with a pretty simple formula:  `countSquareable = n => Math.floor((n + 1) / 2) + Math.floor(n / 4)`

Comment: the fact that all that huge, bulky, inefficient code I've written could be simplified with that simple line puzzles me a lot mate

Comment: It's the difference between *finding* all the solutions and *counting* them (or *recognizing* them.)